# LINQ expression works good in LINQPad, but in Silverlight return empty result

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

This is a simple left outer join in LINQ (like the MS example). 
It works good in LINQPad:

```
from x in Nevtars
join c in Tetsziks on x.NevtarID equals c.NevtarID into ctemp
from subc in ctemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { x.Nev, subc.Tetszes }


The result:
-----------------
Nev    Tetszes
Őszike   1
Őzike    null
Pintyőke null
Regő     null
Rezső    null
Szellő   null
Szellőke 2
```

This expresion in Silverlight DomainSource side:

```
public IQueryable<MyP> GetTetszik()
{
 var q2 = from x in this.Context.Nevtars
 join c in this.Context.Tetszik on x.NevtarID equals c.NevtarID into ctemp
 from subc in ctemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new MyP
 {
   Nev = x.Nev,
   Tetszes = (subc == null ? 0 : (Int32)subc.Tetszes)
 };
 return q2;
}

public class MyP
{
  [Key]
  public string Nev { get; set; }
  public int Tetszes { get; set; }
}
```

And in the "Entity side":

```
DomainService1 ctx2 = new DomainService1();
xxxGrid.ItemsSource = ctx2.MyPs;
var q2 = ctx2.GetTetszikQuery();
ctx2.Load(q2);
```

The result will be an empty grid... :(

Please help me! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the domain service provide a way for the `ItemsSource` to catch the changes? If not, reassign it to the  `ItemsSource` after you grabbed the data from the database.

Comment: The ItemSource catched the change, and I try to reasign too, but the a result is the same. :( I tried the simple select the first table and then the second table and then the grid give the simple result of the tables.